# Connecting AngularJS and CodeIgniter (GET calls working but POST not)

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, post

EDIT: It works on IE!!! So my Chrome and Mozilla must be blocking the POST call. FYR: I've got a Allow-Control-Allow-Origin installed on Chrome.

---

I would like to connect AngularJS (I'm running it in a JavaScript framework - npm, gulp and bower - on MyDocuments) and CodeIgniter (which is on XAMPP).

GET calls work fine (I get the user names and their cities on my screen via AngularJS).

But I have a problem to run this POST function (which adds a new user into the database):

```
$scope.addUser = function(name,city) {
    $http.post("http://localhost/test/index.php/usercontroller/addUser",{'name':name,'city':city})
        .success(function(response) {$scope.answer=response})
        .error(function(response) {alert('error');$scope.answer = response});
};
```

When I call it it there is an error in the console:

> OPTIONS http://localhost/test/usercontroller/add 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10413sendReq @
>   angular.js:10232$get.serverRequest @ angular.js:9944processQueue @
>   angular.js:14454(anonymous function) @
>   angular.js:14470$get.Scope.$eval @ angular.js:15719$get.Scope.$digest
>   @ angular.js:15530$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:15824(anonymous
>   function) @ angular.js:23095eventHandler @ angular.js:3247 (index):1
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost/test/usercontroller/add. Invalid HTTP status code
>   500

The structure of my folders is as follows:

CODEIGNITER - CONTROLLER

xampp/htdocs/test/application/controllers/usercontroller.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Usercontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('usermodel');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['include'] = 'user/index';
        $this->load->view('user/index', $data);
    }

    public function addUser()
    {
        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $name = $request->name;
        $city = $request->city;
        $id = $this->usermodel->addUser($name,$city);
        if($id)
        {
            echo '{"status" : "success"}';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '{"status" : "failure"}';
        }
    }

    public function getCities()
    {
        $cities = $this->usermodel->getCities();
        echo json_encode($cities);
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        $users = $this->usermodel->getUsers();
        echo json_encode($users);
    }

}
```

CODEIGNITER - MODEL

xampp/htdocs/test/application/models/usermodel.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script allowed');

class Usermodel extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function addUser($name,$city)
    {
        $data = array('name' =>$name,'city' => $city);
        $this->db->insert('user',$data);
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $insert_id;
    }

    public function getCities()
    {
        $sql='SELECT city FROM user';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $city = array();
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $city[]=array("city" => $row->city);
        }
        return $city;
    }

    public function getUsers()
    {
        $sql='SELECT * FROM user';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $user = array();
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $user[]=array(
                "name" => $row->name, 
                "city" => $row->city
            );
        }
        return $user;
    }

}
```

ANGULAR - APP

MyDocuments/test/src/app.js

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

ANGULAR - INDEX.HTML

MyDocuments/test/src/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Test project</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="js/all.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">


        <form novalidate>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
            <div>{{name}}</div>
            <label>City:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="city"/>
            <div>{{city}}</div>
            <button ng-click="addUser(name,city)">Submit</button> 
            <div>Answer:{{answer}}</div>
        </form>

        <h3>Users</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">{{ user.name }}, {{user.city}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ANGULAR - CONTROLLER

MyDocuments/test/src/components/MainController.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("http://localhost/test/index.php/usercontroller/getUsers")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.users = response});

    $http.get("http://localhost/test/index.php/usercontroller/getCities")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.cities = response});

    $scope.addUser = function(name,city) {
        $http.post("http://localhost/test/index.php/usercontroller/addUser",{'name':name,'city':city})
        .success(function(response) {$scope.answer=response})
        .error(function(response) {alert('error');$scope.answer = response});
    };

});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there a problem in the fact that I have a JavaScript framework on MyDocuments and CodeIgniter on XAMPP. I've also tried by putting the whole JavaScript folder (with npm, gulp and bower) on XAMPP (don't know if that is such a good idea but, I've tried it anyway) and I get the same 500 error when running that addUser() POST call.

Another thing that I've tried is that I've put a super simple angular.html (attached at the bottom of this post) directly on xampp/htdocs and in this case the POST call works perfectly.

So I guess there is a problem in the communication between JavaScript (angular, npm, gupl, bower) and CodeIgniter folders.

Any ides what could be done to connect them? The GET calls are working so I guess there should also be a solution for the POST calls. Thank you in advance for any hints.

SUPER SIMPLE ANGULAR.HTML DIRECTLY ON XAMPP/HTDOCS

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">

        <form novalidate>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
            <div>{{name}}</div>
            <label>City:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="city"/>
            <div>{{city}}</div>
            <button ng-click="addUser(name,city)">Submit</button> 
            <div>Answer:{{answer}}</div>
        </form>

        <h3>Users</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">{{ user.name }}, {{user.city}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script>

    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
            console.log('delam');
            $http.get("http://localhost/ekohrana/index.php/usercontroller/getUsers")
        .success(function(response) {$scope.users = response});

        $scope.addUser = function(name,city) {
         $http.post("http://localhost/ekohrana/index.php/usercontroller/addUser",{name:name,city:city})
         .success(function(response) {$scope.answer=response})
         .error(function(response) {alert('error');$scope.answer = response});
         };

    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are making CORS post request, therefore browser is trying to make first OPTIONS call to your backend on same url as POST and when you dont response correctly on OPTIONS request , your frontend will fail.

```
   function __construct() {

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if($method == "OPTIONS") {
            die();
        }
        parent::__construct();
```